# search query ending with .com returning 403 permission error

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, search, http-status-code-403

I am facing a strange case. In my site when user searches any query the url becomes `example.com/search/search-word` and it opens with the search result.

All is well when search query is simple like this. But when someone types `.com` in the end of the search word like `example.com/search/search-word.com` my site returning `403 Forbidden Error`.
 Any clue whats happening ?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^k=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/$ http://www.example.com/search/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\++([^+]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\++([^+]*\++.*)$ $1-$2 [L]
```

Comment: Most likely your .htaccess that's not liking the .com

Comment: You should post the php for this though and any other files such as `.htaccess` if you have one and the OS this is running under; the question is unclear and also seems to be db-related.

Comment: Included in the tags.

Comment: Your acceptance record is questionable also.

Comment: If i exclude the .com keyword search is all fine.

Comment: If you must add it you can always base64_encode the string and base64_decode in the controller part. But it's better just to post the content of your .htaccess in your question.

Comment: included my .htaccess.